# How do you determine the length of dead soft #10 AWG copper magnet wire which will drop 2 volts when there's 15 amperes through it?

Tags: wire, cables

Ignoring skin effect and the temperature rise in the conductor caused by \$ I^2R\$ losses, how do you determine the length of dead soft #10 AWG copper magnet wire which will drop 2 volts when there's 15 amperes through it?

Comment: .02 what? 15 what? 10 what? UNITS!

Comment: PROTIP: Writing a coherent question will go far in getting it answered.

Comment: .02% voltage drop,15a current draw of machine, 10awg wire size

Comment: EDIT your question with the proper detail. Comments are not suitable for showing that kind of extra information.

Comment: Oh, and .02% of what?

Comment: maximum voltage drop in the cable 2.00/.02%

Comment: You're not making any sense.  Voltage is measured in volts, not in percentages. A percentage makes no sense without something for it to be a percentage of.

Comment: sorry this the way it was wrote on this sheet i guess thats why im having trouble with it as well

Comment: You need to know the source voltage before you can calculate what 0.02% of it will be. Then look up the resistivity of 10awg wire in a table (google is your friend) and its simple ohm's law.

Comment: Well, it's easy enough to find the resistance per foot or per meter of wire at a certain gauge. Just google it, there's tables a-plenty. You can calculate the resistance a specific voltage drop at a specific current requires, and from the two you can calculate the wire length.  Without the source voltage you can't know what the voltage drop should be.

Comment: google was helpful on some of the problems but not on this one,im trying to determine length of cable when im given all the other variables such as voltage drop,current draw of machine,and cable size

Comment: But you aren't being given all the variables. You're lacking one - either the source voltage, or the *absolute* voltage drop.

Comment: maximum voltage drop in cable 2.00,current draw of machine 15a,minimum cable size 10awg thats all im given on the sheet,i have to solve for the rest

Comment: Right - is that 2.00 as in 2 volts...?

Comment: yes on this one

Comment: Finally!  Right. Find a table of wire gauges. Should take you all of 5 seconds. The rest is just Ohm's Law and primary school maths.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running 15 amperes through the wire and you want to drop 2 volts across it, then its resistance must be

$$ R = \frac{E}{I} = \frac{2V}{15A} =0.133\ \Omega $$

#10 AWG wire has a resistance of 1 milliohm per foot so, since 0.133 ohms is 133 milliohms, the wire would be 133 feet long, total, going to and from the load.

Comment: i wasnt given the voltage source just the voltage drop 2.00v and the current of the machine 15a plus wire size 10awg

Comment: That's completely different from what you said earlier, but I'll edit my answer anyway.  How about accepting it this time around, OK?

Comment: E over I? Why E instead of V?

Comment: @Passerby: **E** lectromotive force; that's how I learned it.

Comment: You seem to be assuming the material the wire is made from ... it may well be the correct assumption, but ... just saying!

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Yup, the devil's in the details...  I've edited the question enough to take care of most of it, I think.